# What is the purpose of NSPasteboard.WritingOptions?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

[image]

I couldn't find any proper explanation of what NSPasteboard.WritingOptions does.
what does this method do?
what is .promised?

Comment: What do you not understand from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/1525372-writingoptions)?

Comment: "Data for a type with this option is promised, not immediately written." - [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/pasteboard_writing_options)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why such an option is provided. What exactly is the use case for this?